# Override Wagtail Admin login with AllAuth

Tags: django, wagtail, django-allauth

I am trying to override the Django Wagtail admin login with my AllAuth Login page.

I've tried adding the following line from the Documentation to my settings.py

> WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
>   WAGTAILADMIN_USER_LOGIN_FORM = 'admin.site.login'

But I receive this error when I try to visit /admin url that renders the wagtail admin login view.

```
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
WAGTAILADMIN_USER_LOGIN_FORM refers to a form 'admin.site.login' that is not available
```